# looping through results from mysql

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, preg-match

I am having a little bit of trouble searching through my resulting array from mysql.  I have the following code:

```
if($result=$link->query("select s_abbreviation from northwoods.state")) {
if($result->num_rows) {
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if(!preg_match("/".$STATE."/", $row['s_abbreviation'])) {
        $error=true;
        echo "Please enter a valid two letter state abbreviation for the state that your address is located in!";
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The resulting array has 59 rows and I am trying to match the $STATE pattern to at least one of the rows, otherwise echo an error.  The problem is that it matches 1 of the 59 rows but still echos 58 errors because it fails to match the other 58 rows.  Is there a way or modifier i can use so that it searchs through all of the rows and if it finds one match then no errors are sent?

Comment: Why not just put it in your query in a `where` clause? I.e. `where s_abbreviation = '$STATE'`

Comment: like where $STATE in(s_abbreviation)? and then I can check the number of rows returned and if 0 then echo an error if 1 then accepts entry.  I will try that, thanks!

Comment: Sure, you could use an `IN()` or `FIND_IN_SET()` depending on how your db is setup. I edited my comment above btw, with an example, but might not be what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Try it

```
if($result=$link->query("select s_abbreviation from northwoods.state")) {
    if($result->num_rows) {
        $error = true;
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if(preg_match("/".$STATE."/", $row['s_abbreviation'])) {
                $error = false;
            }
        }

        if($error) {
            echo "Please enter a valid two letter state abbreviation for the state that your address is located in!";
        }

    }
}
```

Let me know, if there is any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Even if your code is not "bleeding edge", here is what to do to fix it:

```
if($result=$link->query("select s_abbreviation from northwoods.state")) {
    if($result->num_rows) {
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if(!preg_match("/".$STATE."/", $row['s_abbreviation'])) {
                $error=true;
            }
        }
    }
}
if ($error) {
    echo "Please enter a valid two letter state abbreviation for the state that your address is located in!";
} else {
    echo "OK";
}
```